# How to increase rate limit and use 3-legged authorization for LinkedIn's Community Management API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate the LinkedIn posts API on a website to display my company's posts. I have registered an application on the developer portal, got approval and have been able to use the API in a limited capacity. There are two issues we are trying to solve...

1. It is being throttled to 100 requests per day which is not enough.
2. 2-legged authorization doesn't work when using the `r_organization_social` scope on the Community Management API. We would like to use 2-legged instead of 3-legged to avoid coupling our authentication to the API with an individual's LinkedIn account.

After asking ChatGPT, it has suggested to apply for the partnership program (specifically the Marketing Developer Program) to resolve these issues. I would like confirmation whether or not this is what we should do to resolve our issues or if there is a better alternative we can take. I have also seen the "Request upgrade" button for the Community Management API on the linkedin developer portal. Maybe this is a solution? [Image of the upgrade btn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzlF3.png) Thank you!